How Monte Carlo Method Integration Changes Snapshots Approach in Proper Orthogonal Decomposition
I am trying to understand how we can use Monte Carlo integration methods to calculate a POD basis over a high-dimensional parameter space (using the snapshots approach). I get the feeling I'm missing something very basic and would really appreciate some help better understanding what's going on. In particular, I need help understanding how the snapshot setup resulting from this theory differs from the basic snapshot method for calculating the POD basis.
To set the MC integration up I consider the continuous analogue of the K matrix to be
\begin{equation}
    Kw = \int_P u_h(\mu) (w,u_h(\mu))_2 d\mu
\end{equation}
where $P$ is a high-dimensional parameter space (from Quarteroni Reduced Basis Methods Book). Then each entry of the matrix $K$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
    K = \int_P u_h(\mu)u_h^T(\mu)d\mu
\end{equation}
Note that $d \mu = p(\mu) d\vec{x} $ here since we will pick some $\mu$ from a distribution with probability density function $p(\mu)$. To estimate this via the Monte Carlo Integration Method we take $N$ many i.i.d samples of $\mu$, namely $\mu_1, ...,\mu_N$, and we get
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{N} \sum _{i = 1} ^ N u_h(\mu_i)u_h^T(\mu_i)
\end{equation}
since $\int_P p(\mu) d\vec{x} = 1$. Now following how Holmes et. al. set up their eigenvalue problem to find the POD basis -- we find eigenvectors $\varphi$ such that
\begin{equation}
    \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum _{i = 1} ^ N u_h(\mu_i) u_h^T(\mu_i) \right) \varphi = \lambda \varphi.
\end{equation}
In this same resource they go on to say we can calculate the basis by creating a snapshot matrix $X = [u(\mu_1) ... u(\mu_N)]$ and then solving the above eigenvalue problem by solving
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{N} XX^T\varphi = \lambda \varphi.
\end{equation}
So my main question is how is calculating this different from the normal method of snapshots? This seems to be basically the same thing except for the $\frac{1}{N}$.
Since it's Monte Carlo I was expecting to have to do an average somewhere explicitly so I am confused. Can someone please let me know if I'm on the right track and give me some more intuition/instruction on how to compute the POD basis using Monte Carlo Integration combined with the snapshots method?
